# How to modify the json value generated by the ModelSerializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created the following serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'url', 'username', 'email', 'password',
        )
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

I also implemented the create and update methods.
Now, if I try to create a user with the following data:

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "email": "foo@thefoo.net",
    "password": "foo2016"
}
```

I would get the following json response:

```
{
    "url": "http://someurl.com/catalog/api/users/11/",
    "username": "foo",
    "email": "foo@thefoo.net"
}
```

What I would like to have is a JSON response that has an attribute indicating whether the operation is successful, as follows:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "url": "http://someurl.com/foo/users/11/",
        "username": "foo",
        "email": "foo@thefoo.net"
    }
}
```

If an error occurred, the response would look like this:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": {
        "username": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

and shouldn't be like this:

```
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is to improve the error handling on the front-end side.

Comment: In my opinion, these kind of errors are for the developer of front-end side. If by documentation of your API, some field is required, then front-end side should require end user to input that field, and not allow doing the request. If the request without required field is done though, then this error message is supposed for the developer of front-end side, to understand why request failed.

Comment: Also, if you want to know if request has succeeded you can look up HTTP response code. In case of "This field is required" kind of error, HTTP code would be 400 - Bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class Meta, you would be able to add `extra_kwargs` like `extra_kwargs = {'success': True}`

Please refer to the documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

I hope that helps. But I agree with Zhandos Zhylkaidar regarding checking the HTTP Response code for HTTP errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are altering the result, you should override the [renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#advanced-renderer-usage) so that it wraps the serializer content into:

```
{
    "success": false/true,
    "data": <content>
}
```